# Origin of "пять"?

Tags: этимология

Does the word пять have an origin in an Indian language? I noticed that the word in Bengali sounds almost the same. See [here](http://www.omniglot.com/language/numbers/bengali.htm) for the spelling, and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XC6iKTGCC8) for the pronunciation.

Comment: There is a site Linguistics.SE, maybe you should try asking there. http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You may find it interesting that the English word "punch" (the beverage) in fact originates from an Indic word meaning "five".

Comment: @Quassnoi it's a theory - pretty accepted but not the only one - there's also a word puncheon - http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=puncheon -which has nothing to do with India but could be related to punch.

Comment: @MartinPeters a-ha-ha more or less because exactly this kind of reasons european linguistics was born ) Actually a lot of words have PIE roots but yes, it's more of a Linguistics SE kind of question.

Answer (score 4):

Updating my answer: Not Indian but Proto-Indo-European (PIE) from which a huge number of modern and ancient languages (commonly known as Indo-European) have evolved, including Sanskrit, Old Greek, Latin, and, eventually, most modern European languages (Roman, Germanic, Baltic, Slavic), Hindi, etc.

П.С.: надеюсь, я не нарушу слишком много правил, если добавлю источник для интересующихся тем, как из одного древнего слова получается "пять", "five", "cinque" и т.д? 
Для начинающих: 
[Зализняк. "Об исторической лингвистике"](http://flibusta.is/b/270015/read)

Comment: Hm, but in German it is _fünf_ and in Swedish _fem_ which look different.

Comment: Perhaps you can point me to a source when you will have the time.

Comment: With pleasure but I have two problems here:  1. I read my Linguistics books in Russian (that's why I somewhat struggling with English terminology) and I'm not sure if you speak any Russian.   2. A quick search on Google does not show much info suitable for a non-specialist (I searched in English). It's either WiKi with questionable quality of materials, or some specialist-oriented papers, which you might find too hard to grind. :)

Comment: I can read Russian reasonably well.

Comment: Final comment: as you can see the rules of the site forbid long chats. Feel free to ask your "in German it is fünf and in Swedish fem which look different." question on Linguistics.SE

Comment: @MartinPeters Germanic laguages do have an F in many places where related languages had P, don't they? Consider words like Vater, for example. Similarly, fünf had a P a very long time ago when German was not yet German. Google **Grimm's law** if you want more details.

Comment: @MartinPeters - The  Scandinavian _fem_ ("five") < Old Norse _fimm_ < Proto-Germanic _*fimf_ < Proto-Indo-European _*pénkʷe_ ‎(“five”).